# How can I track Google Container Engine services from Stackdriver?

Tags: kubernetes, stackdriver, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm currently trying to set up Stackdriver so I can track availability of the various pods/services running in my cluster, but I can't find a way to do any tracking more granular in resource groups than instances. There's the ability to filter resources by "tag" but no documentation on what a tag is, or if the "name" tag corresponds to the pod name/service name/container image name/etc.

All I want is a resource group to track my service containers; how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Tags or labels  can be assigned during the creation of the service, pod, etc. See [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/)

Afterwards you will be able to "group by label" from the Stackdriver Dashboard, using your assigned labels.

Also yes, there is the possibility of more granular monitoring than instance or node. Go to Stackdriver "Metrics explorer" and select "GKE Container" as the "resource type". This lets you monitor a variety of metrics at pod level. Also, if you assigned label to your pods you can use those for filtering and grouping in a meaningful way for you.

> I'm trying to avoid monitoring at pod level; I'm trying to monitor at cluster level

The set up will differ depending on what metric absence you want to alert, but it could go like this:

- Log into the Stackdriver dashboard
- Go to groups -> create group
- You should see a suggestion to create a group formed by all your GKE nodes. If you don't create one using the common part of the node
  name as the criteria
- Select "This is a cluster. I would like cases highlighted when any node's performance or configuration differs from others in the
  cluster."
- Now you have a group representing your cluster. Click on "create alerting policy"
- Create the policy you need. It will apply to the members of the
  group.

  If I understood you correctly this should be what you need.

Comment: Yep, got that together; the new challenge I'm finding though is that assigning an alert condition of "metric absence" alerts me whenever a specific pod goes down, which isn't what I want in a cluster--that means I get notified whenever someone rolls out a deployment, which isn't ideal.

Comment: Well, that means you probably could get an alert if a time a pod is  killed and rescheduled which does sound less than ideal. 

What are you trying to monitor at pod level? Pods can get killed an rescheduled for lots of reasons, so you don't want to raise alerts for than.

Comment: That's the thing, I'm trying to avoid monitoring at pod level; I'm trying to monitor at cluster level. I haven't been able to find a way to define a policy that works at a cluster level though.

Basically, I'm trying to find metric absence across an entire set of pods as a cluster and currently it's tracking every individual pod.

Comment: Thanks for the update ! That doesn't really solve my answer though honestly--that gives me a group of instances, whereas what I really need is a group of active containers. Still trying to figure that one out.

Comment: Have you tried the new Stackdrive Kubernetes Monitoring? This might be what you need https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-monitoring/

Answer (score 0):

Two days ago, in #KubeCon 2018 event, the Product manager of Stackdriver (JD Velasquez) announced the beta release of Kubernetes monitoring.

https://youtu.be/aa8cgmfHTAs (announcement + demo)

It is now out-of-the-box.